# Symbol not found: _PEM_read_bio_EC_PUBKEY Importing M2Crypto-0.20.2 when compiled against openssl 0.9.8x or 1.0.0x

Tags: python, openssl, m2crypto

Importing M2Crypto version 0.20.2 on python 2.6.5 fails when M2Crypto was compiled against a recent openssl versions (0.9.8x or higher) on MAC OS X 10.4.11:

Even though the compilation works against these openssl version, M2Crypto fails to import, because a missing symbol: _PEM_read_bio_EC_PUBKEY

Python 2.6.5 (r265:79359, Mar 24 2010, 01:32:55) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import M2Crypto
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "M2Crypto/**init**.py", line 22, in 
> > >           import _*m2crypto
> > >       ImportError: dlopen(M2Crypto/*_m2crypto.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PEM_read_bio_EC_PUBKEY
> > >         Referenced from: M2Crypto/__m2crypto.so
> > >         Expected in: dynamic lookup

If I compile M2Crypto against openssl version 0.9.7l or 0.9.7m it works just fine.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 10.4.11, but I do have 10.5.8 with Python 2.6.5 and OpenSSL 0.9.8n and everything works without a problem. Please try with latest M2Crypto. If that does not work, try getting and compiling OpenSSL yourself and configuring M2Crypto to use that. Maybe something is wrong with your current OpenSSL.